# Aws WorkMail Organizations ClientToken

Tags: amazon-web-services, request, token, idempotent, amazon-workmail

In the create organizations api there is a field called

`ClientToken` and the definition is

`The idempotency token associated with the request.`.

Could someone explain the meaning of this action?
How could I make usage of that field?

I don't think I understand the meaning of the principle at a high level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Idempotency ensures that an API request completes no more than one time. ([Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Run_Instance_Idempotency.html))

In this context ClientToken is a unique string that you can use to ensure that you don't accidently re-run the same API request more than once. (In this case, it helps us ensure that we don't create duplicate AWS Workmail Organizations. )